# Como passar um ID de uma tabela gerada por um Foreach para um Modal em PHP?

Tags: php, foreach, modal

Não estou conseguindo pegar o ID de uma tabela gerada por um Foreach onde no Button de excluir existe um modal para confirmar a exclusão, podem nao estou conseguindo enviar o ID do registro da tabela para o Modal enviar a tela de processamento o ID daquele registro, não uso nenhum tipo de JS no momento so estou usando no momento `PHP`. desculpem caso nao tenha ficado claro minha pergunta pois sou iniciante em programação.

```
<tr class="">
    <td class="text-center"><?= $real_carencia["tipo_vaga"] ?></td>
    <td class="text-center"><?= $real_carencia["disciplina"] ?></td>
    <td class="text-center"><?= $real_carencia["matutino"] ?></td>
    <td class="text-center"><?= $real_carencia["vespertino"] ?></td>
    <td class="text-center"><?= $real_carencia["noturno"] ?></td>
    <td class="text-center"><?= $real_carencia["matutino"] + $real_carencia["vespertino"] + $real_carencia["noturno"] ?></td>
    <td class="text-center"><?= $real_carencia["cadastro"] ?></td>
    <td class="text-center"><?= $real_carencia["nome"] ?></td>
    <td class="text-center"><?= $real_carencia["motivo_vaga"] ?></td>
    <td class="text-center"><?= date('d/m/Y', strtotime($real_carencia["inicio_vaga"])); ?></td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <!-- <a title="Suprir" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-user-plus"></i></a> -->
        <a title="Detalhar" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="./details-carencia.php?id=<?= $real_carencia["id"] ?>"><i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i></a>
        <a title="Excluir" type="button" class="btn text-white btn-sm btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ExemploModalCentralizado"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Este e o meu modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ExemploModalCentralizado" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="TituloModalCentralizado" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header d-flex justify-content-center">
            <h4 class="modal-title text-center text-dark" id="TituloModalCentralizado"><strong>Excluir Dados</strong></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <strong>O registro sera excluido permanentemente !</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            <a title="Excluir Carência" href="./crud/delete-carencia.php?id=<?= $real_carencia["id"] ?>"><button type="button" class="btn float-right btn-danger"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i> Excluir</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você pode colocar um onclick ao clicar no botão para abrir o modal, esse onclick chamaria uma função que enviaria o id.
Tipo:

```
onclick="abrirModal(<?= $real_carencia["id"] ?>)"
```

E então, no javascript, você usaria o id para editar os textos do modal, exemplo:

```
function abrirModal(id){
    document.getElementById("iddobotaodeexcluir").href="./crud/delete-carencia.php?id=" + id; //adicionar o id dinâmico no modal
    document.getElementById("ExemploModalCentralizado").modal(); //função para abrir o modal
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado mano, funcionou perfeitamente, ainda estou estudando JS, obrigado de verdade